# CSR8675 programming and build

Tags: bluetooth, audio, csr-adk

I've bought myself a simple CSR8675 board with USB-SPI programmer, without any software included. I've succesfully managed to read and edit some settings using PSTool, but what i really need is to set it up as A2DP music transmitter. From what i found, I need to compile and program it with `source` example application. I've found and downloaded both ADK for this chip and BlueLab 4.1.2, but I have no idea how to use them properly. When I try to compile `source` example project, error `Hardware Variant must be set in project properties.  Stop.` occurs, when i try to select my chip, it isn't present on the list. Then I've noticed that ADK folder structure is very similar to Bluelab's and tried to replace its files with ADK ones. WHen i try to compile VM or DSP libs i get errors like missing files or makefiles. How am I supposed to do it correctly?

Comment: Maybe you could get help on a Qualcomm forum?

Comment: Not sure...but might be helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXERwuX3UYM